# How to retrive more than 5000 record from CRM using kingswaysoft for SSIS packages?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, kingswaysoft

I am trying to migrate data between two CRM databases(dynamics 365) but when in kingswasoft there is limit of 5000 record per batch. can anyone please suggest an approach wherein I can send n number of records?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We will page through all records in the source entity. The **Batch Size** setting on the CRM Source component is just used to specify how many records you want to retrieve **per service call**, not the total number you will get from the source entity. Hope this clarifies things a bit more.